# SQL update for the varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I want to  change the string of  `AttachmentCopyLoc` columns from `D:\IT\Public\FTX_RobotAlerts\336` to `V:\IT\Public\FTX_RobotAlerts\336` only change here is D to V, the remaining string is the same (I don't event want to change that).

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: i have 12k rows to update.. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: What server software are you using?  String replacement functions can be different in different platforms.

Comment: Can you please add a tag with the specific RDBMS engine and syntax you're doing this in? There are so many.

Comment: i am using SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way would be basic string manipulation

```
UPDATE {table}
SET AttachmentCopyLoc ='V' + substring(AttachmentCopyLoc,2,len(AttachmentCopyLoc )) 
where AttachmentCopyLoc like 'D%'
```

Answer (score 2):

The exact syntax depends on the platform, but it would be something akin to

```
UPDATE {table}
SET AttachmentCopyLoc = REPLACE ( AttachmentCopyLoc , 'D:' , 'V:' )  
WHERE AttachmentCopyLoc LIKE 'D:%'
```

Comment: @D Stanley .. Thanks for your help, but somehow its giving me error like "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'D:'." , not sure why...but the next ans of Cableload is work for me..

Comment: See my update - I was using the wrong quote identifier

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, I would recommend using `stuff()`:

```
update t
    set AttachmentCopyLoc = stuff(AttachmentCopyLoc, 1, 1, 'V')
    where AttachmentCopyLoc like 'D:%';
```

This version has two advantages:

1. The use of `STUFF()` ensures that only the first occurrence of `'D:'` is replaced.  Admittedly, it is unlikely that this substring occurs more than once in the column, but why take the chance?
2. The use of `LIKE` allows an index on `AttachmentCopyLoc` to be used, if one is available and use of hte index is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This will only alter the first letter of the string:

```
update <tablename>
set AttachmentCopyLoc = 'V'+substring(AttachmentCopyLoc,2,len(AttachmentCopyLoc)-1)
```